# Mongoose: how to set a query that $in everything if there is no value selected?

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to apply the filter to my aggregate search right now. Currently, I can't set the value `$in:` to include everything.

```
if (gameType.length === 0) {
    query = {
      gameCode: {
        $in: gameCode,
      },
   
    };
  } else {
    query = {
      gameType: {
        $in: gameType,
      },
      gameCode: {
        $in: gameCode,
      },
    };
  }
```

The above code is what I have. Users can select more than one `gameType`. Because, I don't know how to set `$in` to include everything, I have used the `if statement` to exclude `gameType` from the query when user has not selected any = returning all the `gameType`.

Is there any way that I can set a variable to search every `gameType` besides providing the array with all the values (I will probably do that if there is no way that I can do this)?

Comment: Why? Just omitting the filter property returns everything (i.e., does not filter)? What's the point in trying to "include everything" rather than "not exclude/filter anything"?

Comment: Am trying to do a conditional for the query. Later, I will add more filter fields. And, I can't do `if statement` for every possibility in that case. So, I wondered if there is any way that I can set `return all` variable when user has not selected any of the choices.

Comment: Got it, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many different filter options, you can just build your query dynamically:

```
const query: FilterQuery<Game> = {};
if (gameType.length) {
  query.gameType = {$in: gameType};
}
if (gameCode.length) {
  query.gameCode = {$in: gameCode};
}
// ...
```

You can add more if statements if you have more conditions.
Keep in mind that all conditions are ANDed, i.e. all must be true.

Comment: Right. In case that I want to do like `or`, then I will prob wrap the query to `$or` object like this? I almost got here but stuck at adding `$in`. Forgot about `{}`. Thank you so much mate!

Comment: Yes, you could use something like `query = {$or: [{gameType: ...}, {gameCode: ...}]}`. Or put the array in a variable and add the conditions as needed :)